# Animation not working after segue in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, segue, swift2

I'm working on an iOS application written in Swift 2. In Swift 1.2, animation worked fine across all views. After migrating to Swift 2, animation only works in the first view; after a segue, the SKSpriteNodes on the new view do not respond to animation.

Here is the animation code:

```
    let frames = [
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "1"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "2"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "3"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "4"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "5"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "TRc5"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "TRc4"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "TRc3"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "TRc2"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed: "TRc")
    ]
    let ani = SKAction.animateWithTextures(frames, timePerFrame: 0.05)
    img.runAction(ani)
```

And here is the segue code:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        if (scene.touchToWorld(touch)) {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("startToGame", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked through the summary of changes in Swift 2 and as far as I can tell no significant changes to SpriteKit animations have been made; any thoughts on why animations might not be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to Xcode 7 Beta 3 and the issue disappeared. I suppose Xcode 7 Beta 1 was quite a beta...